# div id exists in webpage or not using casperjs

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I tried to code as below:

```
//var url = 'https://www.google.com.kh/';
var url = 'https://teleservices.paris.fr/etatcivil/jsp/site/RunStandaloneApp.jsp?page=formengine&form=naissance';

var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start(url, function() {
    this.echo('Page: ' + this.getTitle());
    this.capture('start1.png');
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.capture('beforesearch.png');
    //in this part I got the error too cos I can not detect div, div#formengine-form-content whether it has or not.
if(this.exists("div#formengine-form-content")){
        this.echo("this is id found");
} else {
        this.echo("no ID found");
    }
});

casper.run();
```

I have problem with the url if I put the other url like `https://www.google.com.kh/` the code works but if I change the url to `https://teleservices.paris.fr/etatcivil/jsp/site/RunStandaloneApp.jsp?page=formengine&form=naissance` it does not work. I cannot get the title of the website. I want to test that is has or has not the div with id, but it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a useragent to your casper request.  It may be that the second site is catching you in some sort of honeypot where you aren't really getting the page back because they know you're a bot.

```
casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X)');
```